# Example of an iterative O(2^n) algo

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

As the title says what is an example of an iterative O(2^n) algo? When does it normally happen?

Comment: Basically any algorithm, where you brute-force check each combination of input elements. Knapsack might be an example. However, oftentimes there are better approaches.

Comment: What do you mean by that? Like if I_n were the set of all inputs, if the algo ran through the entire I_n it'd be O(2^n)?

Comment: You can view the problem in for each element you can assign a 1, if the element is part of the solution, or 0, if not. This assigns a binary number to the input with as many digits as you have input elements (n), resulting in 2^n possible solutions. If checking each possible solution takes O(1) you get O(2^n) overall, if you check all solutions (brute force).

Comment: Just output all the different strings of length n made of 0 and 1 (and without cache...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tower of Hanoi can be a good example.

Tower of Hanoi consists of three rods or pegs with n disks placed one over the other.

The objective of the puzzle is to move the entire stack to another rod following these 3 rules.

1.Only one disk can be moved at a time.
2.Each move consists of taking the upper disk from one of the stacks and placing it on top of another stack or on an empty rod.
3.No larger disk may be placed on top of a smaller disk.

The minimal number of moves required to solve a Tower of Hanoi puzzle is 2^n − 1, where n is the number of disks.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi#Iterative_solution

Answer (score 1):

This [link](https://developerinsider.co/big-o-notation-explained-with-examples/) explains it better, but an algorithm with order O(2^n) is usually a greedy algorithm. The most greedy I know is O (n ^ n).
The fibonacci recovery algorithm, without using a value memorization technique, is an example of an O (2 ^ n) algorithm.

example(python)

```
def fib(n):
    if n == 0: return 1
    if n == 1: return 1
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
```

In line 4 we have that the function is called twice. This means that the iterative method will occur will be called 2 times each call.

---

For something strictly iterative you can consider the example (code in python):

```
def O2n(n):
    a = 0
    while True:
        if a < 2**n:
            a = a + 1
        else:
            break
    return a
```

In the code I force the algorithm to be O (2 ^ n) through a condition.
It is not a practical example, but using a condition it is possible to obtain different order algorithms.

Comment: But what about a strictly iterative algo, i.e, no recursive calls?

Comment: Isn't Fibonacci without memoization `O(phi^n)`, where `phi` is approximately `1.618`? While I agree that an algorithm that runs in `O(1.618^n)` time also runs in `O(2^n)` time, I feel it's in the spirit of the question to receive an answer in which `2^n` is the smallest function that works (so actually big-theta). Otherwise, we would just be able to provide any linear algorithm and claim that it satisfies OP's `O(2^n)` requirement (which, formally, it does, but I don't think that's what they're looking for). That being said, I think your iterative algorithm is a good example.